# find a hyperlink in Gmail body python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, gmail-imap, imaplib

**I am making a program to automatically read emails and click automatically a  hyperlink in that email body**.

A taxi company provides contractions from email. immediately need to click on link in email.

I am using **imaplib** , **selenium** , **re** to code this.
I successfully coded the login to email using imaplib and read mail.

Now **i need to get hyperlink from mail**.(hyperlink text is confirm)
code given below

```
import imaplib 
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxx')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest

result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID

raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email
# including headers and alternate payloads
print(raw_email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each email, try the following:

```
print(re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString).group("url"))
```